# Do I have to pick up my luggage at Seoul Incheon and how many bags am I able to check?

Tags: transit, luggage, air-canada, icn, asiana-airlines

I am flying to Singapore from Toronto.  My route is Toronto to Seoul - Air Canada and then codeshare Asiana Airlines from Seoul to Singapore- all booked on the same ticket.  I have looked online and asked my travel agent but getting conflicting confusing information on a couple of things.

First do I have to pick up my luggage at Incheon and recheck them on Asiana or will my luggage be tagged right through to Singapore from Toronto?

Secondly does anyone know if you can check 2 bags free for international flights?  I know I can from Toronto to Incheon on Air Canada but it says maybe subject to Asiana Airline check baggage which could be different from AC.  I checked the Asiana website and find the information to be very confusing.

https://www.flyasiana.com/C/US/EN/contents/free-baggage

Any information you can provide or share your experience if you have flown this route would be appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: @MichaelHampton "all booked on a single ticket". And what difference would telling us the flight numbers make?

Comment: @DavidRicherby The flight originates in Canada, so if the flight is an AC code then AC's baggage rules will apply to the entire journey. It does seem odd to me that the travel agent could not find out which airline's baggage rules will apply.